# Rails 4 + jQuery: Live preview form input with helper method

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a new recipe form in my app and I'd like to give the user a **live** preview of their post before submission.  I found a relatively simple way to to make this work for the name of the recipe:

```
$(".health-form-section input").on("keyup", function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $('#show_recipe' + ' ' + '.' + $this.attr('id') + '').html($this.val());
});
```

...where my view has the following

```
<div id="show_recipe">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1 class="recipe_name"></h1> <!-- This gets updated -->
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

But the problem arises when I need to format the text before displaying it.
I normally display the text like this so that I can provide an array of ingredients and display them as an html list.  Should I use a helper function?  How would I pass the text to the function?

```
<div class="show-ingredients">
    <strong>Ingredients:</strong>
    <ul class="ing-list">
        <% @recipe.ingredients.split("\n").each do |ing| %>
        <li><%= ing unless ing.blank? %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
```